# How can I print all the even numbers

Tags: python, python-itertools

I wanted to print all the even numbers that exist in this nums list

```
from itertools import takewhile

nums = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

a = takewhile(lambda x: x%2==0, nums) 

print(a)
```

but the output is `<itertools.takewhile object at 0x00C462B0>`

Comment: `takewhile` stops on the first falsy evaluation of the predicate, and you need to call `list` on it to see the result: `list(a) -> []`

Comment: how about `a = [x for x in nums if x%2 == 0]`